# SQL Server : order date and orders before

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple table of `Customers` (customerID) and a table of `Orders` (orderID, orderdate)

I need to get a list of all customers that got an order exactly two weeks ago, and the count of all the orders that they had until that week.

```
SELECT c.id_customer
FROM customer AS c
JOIN order AS o ON o.customerID = c.customerID
WHERE o.delivery_date = DATEADD(Day,-14,GETDATE())
```

But I don't know how to get the count of orders until *that* week exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<=` to get the rows and use `having` clause to check if there is a row present exactly on the given date:

```
select c.id_customer, count(*) as order_count
from customer as c
join orders as o on o.customerID = c.customerID
where o.delivery_date <= DATEADD(Day, - 14, GETDATE())
group by c.id_customer
having count(case when o.delivery_date = DATEADD(Day, -14, GETDATE()) then 1 end) > 0;
```

Also note that I changed table name `order` to `orders` as `order` is SQL reserved keyword and it is usually a bad idea to use keyword as table/column identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.customerID,o.orderID, count(o.delivery_date)
FROM customer AS c
JOIN order AS o ON o.customerID = c.customerID
WHERE o.delivery_date = DATEADD(Day,-14,GETDATE())
group by c.customerID,o.orderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with other sample data,

```
 Declare @DaysAgo int=14 --para to be pass in proc
    declare @To Datetime=DATEADD(second,-1,cast((DATEADD(Day, - (@DaysAgo-1), cast(GETDATE() as date)) ) as DATETIME))
   declare @From Datetime=cast((DATEADD(Day, - @DaysAgo, cast(GETDATE() as date)) ) as DATETIME)


    select c.id_customer, count(*) as order_count
    from customer as c
    join orders as o on o.customerID = c.customerID
    where o.delivery_date >= @From AND 
    o.delivery_date <= @To
    group by c.id_customer
```